# Beginning the implementation of a Linkedlist class in c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

For an assignment, I have to implement the list class, and I'm running into many errors after trying to set up the header file. For example, there are errors where I define reference back() and front() saying they do not name a type.

edit: These errors were fixed after adding the template for element_type

Right below is the default constructor I came up with...

```
#include "Linkedlist.h"
#include <cstddef> //need this to use NULL?

template<typename element_type>
Linkedlist<element_type>::Linkedlist()
{
    head->elem = 0;
    head->prev = NULL;
    head->next = NULL;
    tail = head;
}
```

I think I do not have a good understanding of the use of element_type in this class... However, is the default constructor above, a good start? It compiles for me, but there could still be some issues with it that I just cannot see. My professor gave us freedom on how to define the node structure, and the only thing given was the public member functions of the class.

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

using namespace std;

template<typename element_type>
class Linkedlist
{
public:


    typedef element_type& reference;
    typedef const element_type& const_reference;
    Linkedlist(); //default constructor for empty list
    ~Linkedlist(); //destructor to free nodes dynamically created to support 
    the linklist
    bool empty() const;
    void clear();
    reference back();
    const_reference back() const;
    reference front();
    const_reference front() const;
    Linkedlist& operator=(const Linkedlist& l);
    void pop_back ( );
    void pop_front ( );
    void push_back ( const element_type& x );
    void push_front ( const element_type& x );
    void sort ( );
    // constructor that initializes the linked list with n nodes,
    // with elem value from 0 to n-1
    explicit Linkedlist(unsigned int n);
    // print the linked list in the forward direction,
    // similar to the show function of lab6
    void check() const;
    // print the linked list in the backward direction,
    // similar to the reverse_show function of lab7
    void rcheck() const;
    // insert a node with value specified by x after the node
    // specified by pos. The first node has position 0.
    // if the number of nodes in the linked list is less than
    // pos, the node is inserted at the end.
    void insert(unsigned int pos, const element_type& x);
    // remove the node specified by pos.
    // if the number of nodes in the linked list is less than
    // pos, the node at the end if any is removed.
    void erase(unsigned int pos);

        struct Node
        {
            element_type elem;  // Data
            Node * next;        // Pointer to the next node in the chain
            Node * prev;        // Pointer to the previous node in the chain
        };
private:

    Node * head;
    Node * tail;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare `LinkedList` to `Linkedlist`.

Now that you changed your question and fixed the typo: Template classes should be implemented in the header file.

The code you've shown causes a lot of errors but not the one you mentioned.

```
template<typename element_type>
class Linkedlist
{ // ...
};

// ...

template <typename element_type>
Linkedlist<element_type>::Linkedlist()
{ // ...
```

... and uncomment the `typedef`s.

Comment: I must not have a good understanding of template classes. I know the list class in c++ is something like list<data_type>... Do I need to have that same syntax? As of right now I have not used <> anywhere. The use of element_type and reference is still pretty new to me.

Comment: One thing I'm thinking about now... In the default constructor is it ok to set head's elem to 0 even though it is not defined as an integer?

Comment: @user2803082 You should give your `Node` a constructor (with some default values for parameters often used with the same values) and initialize `Node::elem` with `element_type()`.